# Random sorting between two sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 Excel sheets. Sheet 1 has 11,000 rows and 5 columns with active record, sheet 2 has 26,000 rows and 10 columns.

My challenge is I want to filter the 11,000 records in sheet 1 which is randomly in the 26,000 records in sheet 2. Is there a script or something I can do on Excel itself to achieve this feat.

Comment: how you want them filtered? Does the `active record` in sheet1 have any impact since that's not mentioned in sheet2?
What attempt have you done at this point?

Comment: Some of the records in sheet 1 are the ones i'm trying to get out of sheet 2, because the sheet 2 has a more complete information of the records. And doing it manually will take ages to complete. Looking at comparing the 2 sheets so i can delete records that are not in both sheets

Comment: what if you use formula `Index` and add a "X/Yes" or what ever to every hit in an extra column. If u need that to a New sheet there are loads of hits in Google for that like [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470007/copy-all-cells-with-certain-value-into-another-column-skipping-blanks)